# Ошибка последовательности действий

Tags: python, pyautogui

Вообщем моя цель чтобы при каждом входе в дискорд генерировался 20 значный пароль и применялся на аккаунт, грубо говоря при каждом входе в дискорд обновлялся пароль, с помошью горячих клавиш `tab` я ориентируюсь по дискорду, но когда дело доходит до смены пароля происходит что то странное, я проверил раз 5 и в коде я всё верно прописал, когда генерируеться новый пароль и вписываеться старый(чтобы изменить новый), а затем вписываеться новый то пароль просто не изменяеться, тоесть в **txt** файлах записываеться но остаёться прежним (знаю очень странное объяснение). Я надеюсь вы поймёте, я думаю, что я что-то намутил с последовательностью действий.

```
from os import system
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
from random import choice

# Generate new password
def getnewpass():
    # symbols of password
    chars = 'abcdefghijklnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
    
    # How many password generate
    number = 1

    # Doesn't need to coment
    length = 25

    # Generate password
    for n in range(number):
        password =''
        for i in range(length):
            password += choice(chars)

    # Write new password for exctraction
    with open('newpassword.txt', 'w') as new0:
        new0.write(password)

# Extraction new password
with open('newpassword.txt', 'r') as new:
    newpassword = new.readline()

# Extraction old password
with open('oldpassword.txt', 'r') as old:
    oldpassword = old.readline()

# Generate new password
getnewpass()

def login():
    # Auth
    
    # Open Discord.exe
    system("start C:\\Users\\tntwn\\AppData\\Local\\Discord\\app-1.0.9002\\Discord.exe")
    
    #Waiting for open discord
    sleep(10)

    # Click to login input, and write value
    pyautogui.write("loginking333@gmail.com")

    # Click to password input, and write value
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.write(oldpassword)

    # Login
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    sleep(3)
    
    # Open setting
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("enter")

    # Click on button for change password
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("space")
    sleep(1)

    # Write old password
    pyautogui.write(oldpassword)
    pyautogui.press("tab")

    # Write new password
    pyautogui.write(newpassword)
    pyautogui.press("tab")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    sleep(1)

    # Write new changed password for future authorization
    with open('oldpassword.txt', 'w') as old0:
        old0.write(newpassword)
    
    # Loop aplication
    sleep(100)


# start main code
password = input("Tell me the key for open door:")
if password == "Qawsed78101.":
    print("Yello")
    login()
else:
    print("Doesn't fit")
```

Comment: А зачем у вас два пароля и два файла, как они между собой связаны логически?

Comment: Один пароль генерируеться для смены, а второй (oldpassword.txt) для авторизации, вообщем то я уже решил проблему тем что переписал всё на координаты мышки а не на горячии клавишы